# bit-flip error-corecting algorithm

Tags: quantum-information

I'm reading John Watrous's [notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/CPSC519/LectureNotes/16.pdf) about this subject, and I wanted to ask about the circuit for this algorithm which appears on page 4.

[image]

On the left side in the small frame we have the encoding of a qubit into three qubits. In the large frame on the left side we have the erroר-correcting algorithm.

1. What happens in the large frame after the first four gates? According to the ciruit on page 3 there supposed to be a measurement there.
2. What are the white circles? I don't know any quantum gate marked this way.
3. What is a controled-not with two controls (third gate from the right)?
4. Also, why do we care about phase-flip errors? They do not change the amplitude of measurement so they are not even errors?

Comment: Maybe you start by explaining what you *do* understand, so we know where to start from?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch What do you mean? I understand many things. Are my questions not clear?

Comment: They are. But where should one start explaining?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to measure, since after that point the qubits only act as control qubits, i.e., in the classical basis.  It is as good as if they were measured (and then set to the outcome).
2. The white circles are "inverse" controls: The NOT is applied if the control is 0, rather than 1 (as for black dots).
3. The CNOTs with two controls act with a NOT on the target only if both controls have the correct value (i.e., for two black dots: if both are 1).
4. We care about phase flips because they change the state of the qubit.  If we would not care about the phase, i.e., treat the qubit as a classical bit, we would just get back to sth. which is equivalent to a classical circuit.

Comment: 1.  why I don't need to measure? measuring gives me the result of where the flip happened. Also, what is the purpose of the CNoT between the two $|0>$? will it not change the result in the eaxmple $|10>\rightarrow|11>$?
2. What are the three gates from q3 and q2? what purpose do they serve?

Comment: 1. Because you don't need the measurement outcome.  (You need it to correct the error, but this can be done without measuring it, as above.)  Regarding the gates, you'll have to check yourself.  2. Since I don't know what q3 and q2, I don't know.  **BUT**: There are only 8 possible inputs.  You should be able to just work out all 8 cases yourself.